# Checking if id and reg already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this table Profile which has fields with user_Id and regNo and I want to check first if id and email are already exists before proceed to inserting data.

In my code, I am able to validate only one row (either id or reg number), but if I am going to validate the two of them, it gives me an error, saying "Must declare the scalar variable @userid". I don't know if it is with my select that is wrong or something in my code.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GATE-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbProfile;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("select * from Profile where user_Id = @userid AND RegNo = @reg", con);

    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
    //SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@userid";
    param.ParameterName = "@reg";

    param.Value = txtid.Text;
    param.Value = txtregNo.Text;

    cmdd.Parameters.Add(param);
    //cmdd.Parameters.Add(param1);


    SqlDataReader reader = cmdd.ExecuteReader();


        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            MessageBox("User Id/Registry Number already exists");
        }


        else
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GATE-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbProfile;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("qry", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtid.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regno", txtregNo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);

            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox("successfully saved!");

        }
```

I am using C# with asp.net.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so this isn't going to work:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
//SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@userid";
param.ParameterName = "@reg";

param.Value = txtid.Text;
param.Value = txtregNo.Text;

cmdd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

because you're reassigning the value of the same object. Change that to this:

```
cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", txtid.Text);
cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg", txtregNo.Text);
```

this will add the parameters, two of them, to the `SqlCommand` object. **Now, a little more advice, consider doing this:**

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GATE-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbProfile;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("select * from Profile where user_Id = @userid AND RegNo = @reg", con))
    {
        ...

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

because right now you're not disposing those object properly.

You see, anything that implements `IDisposable` should be wrapped in a `using` statement to **ensure** the `Dispose` method is called on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
param.ParameterName = "@userid";
param.ParameterName = "@reg";

param.Value = txtid.Text;
param.Value = txtregNo.Text;
```

You are only declaring 1 parameter and overwriting it for both `ParameterName` and `Value`.

As an aside, you should consider looking into some type of data access helper or ORM or something to save you the trouble of all that boilerplate SQL connection code.

You are also opening another connection inside of what should already be an open SQL connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem as per the error is that you are reassigning the parameter to `@reg` after you assign it to `@userid`.

Try this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GATE-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbProfile;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("select user_id from Profile where user_Id = @userid AND RegNo = @reg", con);


cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", txtid.Text);
cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg", txtregNo.Text);

var id = cmdd.ExecuteReader() as string;

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
{
    //Show error message and exit the method
}
else
{
    //Add the row to the database if it didn't exist
}
```

EDIT:

I added some code to show how you could check if the userId exists in the table.  Then you check against the user id itself instead of checking a `reader` object.  Note, i am not at my dev computer right now so I did not compile this, you may have to do some tweaks but the idea is there.

Comment: hello thanks for replying. I have tried your code suggestion. But it is just validating the reg no, the user id is not validating, it is saving even id is already exists

Comment: Is `id` set as your primary key in the table?

Answer (score 0):

You are using one instance of sql parameter and passing it two different values thus overriding the first one. Try it like this:

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@userid", txtid.Text);

SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@reg", txtregNo.Text);
```

Comment: I have tried also your code suggestion. But it is just validating the reg no, the user id is not validating, it is saving even id is already exists

Comment: my post was about your first error with the parameters. if for some reason you don't want to add a unique index on those two fields on the database, you can always execute `select count(1) from Profile where user_Id = @userid AND RegNo = @reg` if you get `1` then the user already exists other wise you can go ahead with the insert

Comment: you can use another `SqlCommand` and `ExecuteReader()` or an `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataSet`. check this CodeProject out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C